# How to totally disable drill-down in the WPF CrystalReports viewer?

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

When displaying reports that contain subreports, one may want to disable the drill-down feature of CrystalReports' viewer and let the user with only a preview of the global report.

How to do exactly that?

**EDIT:**

Moreover, when moving the mouse pointer above the report viewer, different parts of the report (including the sub-reports) are highlighted with an orange border as in the image below:

[image: Orange border]

Clicking on the item makes this border become red and persistent.

[image: Red border]

Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: So do you want to permanently disable the drill-down, or only on certain criteria?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I want to totally disable the drill-down, and as well remove the highlight border that appears around parts of the report if it's possible... Thanks!

Comment: So is the answer you posted acceptable to you or are you still looking for a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF `CrystalReportsViewer`'s `ViewerCore` member has an `EnableDrillDown` boolean property. So simply put, just do the following:

```
myViewer.ViewerCore.EnableDrillDown = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

When talking about the borders, I'm assuming you are referring to the borders around the subreport. To get rid of those borders you right-click on the subreport in the main report. Click "Format Subreport" and then click the "Borders" tab. Simply change the line style from "single" to "none" and the borders will be gone. Crystal Reports automatically puts those borders around a new subreport.
To disable the drilldown you will have to change the EnableDrillDown Property to false in the CrystalReportViewer properties.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the subreports border, I'm talking about the orange borders that appear when hovering the report with the mouse...